# Get total value of a column from CSV

Tags: vba, vb6

Here i have a code with this i load CSV file.
It see like this:

```
//profile, lenght, width, qty, color//
r2,500,800,5,white
r2,200,100,2,white
```

I parse it with this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim CDLG As Object
    Set CDLG = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog")
    With CDLG
      .DialogTitle = "Choose file"
      .Filter = "CSV Documents|*.csv"
      .ShowOpen
      m_strFileURI = .Filename
      m_strFileName = .FileTitle

    Dim cesta As String
    cesta = Left(m_strFileURI, InStrRev(m_strFileURI, "\"))
    End With
    Set CDLG = Nothing


    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
'array of values in each line
    Dim LineValues() As String
'each new line read in from the text stream
    Dim ReadLine As String
    Dim ts As TextStream
'open file
    Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(m_strFileURI)
'keep going till no more lines
    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
'read first line
    ReadLine = ts.ReadLine

    LineValues = Split(ReadLine, ",")

Debug.Print LineValues(3)


**'--> Need finaly generate filename as:  Totalqty - lenght - width**


Loop
End Sub
```

but how can i get TOTAL QTY from - LineValues(3)
so i can use it for create a filename which contains Totalqty - lenght - width??

thank you

Comment: Is this actually vba? or vb6? They are not the same thing. If it's vba please also include the office application that you are using it with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new variable called TotaLineValues and increment it with each LineValues(3)

At the top of the Sub add this

```
Dim TotalLineValues As Long
TotalLineValues = 0
```

Before the `Loop` add this:

```
TotalLineValues = TotalLineValues + LineValues(3)
Debug.Print TotalLineValues
```

And you will see the total increment by the value each time

EDIT: To query the file and sum the QTY in one go, before you loop through it, try querying it as a SQL object:

```
Public Sub GetDataFromCSV()
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strPathtoTextFile = "C:\temp\"
    strFile = "tesFile.csv"
    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPathtoTextFile & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
    objRecordSet.Open "Select sum(QTY) as Quantity from " & strFile, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then
        Debug.Print objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Quantity") ' This will tell you the total quantity in the file is 7

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: its calculate the qty, but step by step... 1step = 5, 2step=7, but i need to get already in first step the total = 7 ....but thank you

Comment: You are reading the file line by line, you have to count the value up as each line is read...

Comment: yes, because that i ask if is there a way fist get the total of QTY and then ready line by line..

Comment: Yes, you could query the CSV file as a SQL object and sum the qty value directly, before you run the loop on the file.  I've edited the answer to include an example of how you could do this with your example file

Comment: Thank you its working, i just changed it for csv without header